# Realized volatility forecast vs Implied volatility

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility

I have forecasts of realized volatility, as well as implied volatility for individual traded options of the S&P500.

I want to simulate a simple trading strategy; that is, buy signal=1 if forecasted realized volatility is greater than current implied volatility. However, the literature documents that implied volatility is usually higher than realized volatility.

Are there any better approach for this simulation?

Comment: What implied volatility are you talking about?

Comment: Implied volatility for 30 days to expiry options obtained from WRDS. I have deannualized it, but it still appears a notch higher than realized volatility

Comment: What strike are the options? Is there skew?

Answer (score 4):

On average the implied volatility is higher than realized volatility because you can easily imagine that dealers will ask customers to pay a premium to write them options and risk manage them

you can have a look at this paper for instance

[PIMCO-The Volatility Risk Premium](https://www.pimco.com/handlers/displaydocument.ashx?wd=Insight&id=j%2BVXaFRvp05MDLCUtE9OTSdz739HwNMGNUqUx3tJMDuTUgI2juEtJ4XHx3qXQDGLt3tJDquOGWMwSnRqe1Oi20C3mv3fyJk1tySH8HboRxIHYTc4pja3SwwCV%2F407E5RKUJ%2Fc9YuxenjzKGyisgZODh%2BdCDJe7Ng0iM7MET0lz94%2BvC6hnXiUnz4LIMpEF65BDsbR%2BVnWxtJO4n0hKZ8Z2Ej0XP18%2FpDuend5TUogytJGftvYkNs1hhqOG9ucC6eZbETXGE25qu%2BDGnyc7pYwRjMKHRTbLrrUzddN25am%2B4yr3NnjpNVfh1mP1hXlBfZU9DWjXjTiVdO3FFw80mpYQ%3D%3D)

Now you can investigate how realized volatility can be a signal for trading implied vol but the condition will certainly not be "buy when realized > implied" because the 2 quantities are not directly comparable. You need to establish some statistical relationship first.

And to finish here is a little exercise to test your thinking about realized vs implied vol and hopefully help you design properly your strategy: suppose you are long a call option which you purchased at some implied vol level $\sigma_0$ and which you are delta-hedging. Now imagine that i grant you that "on average" over a period of time the stock realized volatility $\sigma_r$ will be higher than $\sigma_0$. In other words i tell you that in expectation $$E[\sigma_r] > \sigma_0$$

Would you be certain to make money even in this situation ?

Comment: I would think yes since forecasted volatility is higher than implied, when it really should be lower on average? (That is if your forecasts make sense)

Comment: @Bryan Lwy actually the answer is no. It would depend on the path the underlying asset takes since when delta-hedged you accumulate the realised vs implied vol discrepancy via the Gamma. You can get "hammered at the strike" as some put it. See an example here: http://www.trade2win.com/boards/attachments/f112/28465d1184429346-gamma-variance-swaps.pdf pp.12-13

Comment: ^^ correct. Indeed an intuitive (and mathematically correct) way of thinking about it is that the pnl of a delta-hedged portfolio is the *gamma-weighed* average of the difference between realized and implied vols. The simple average of the difference can be positive and you still lose money if the gamma is small (out-the-money) when realized vol is high but big when realized vol is small.